# IBM Watson Assistant: How to enable user metrics

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

We want know how many times each user calls IBM Watson Assistant service from client application and its billing details per user. 
I am trying to enable user metrics for watson assistant service based on this URL(https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/logs_oview.html#user_id) and added the headers and metadata in my node.js code.
But when I check the **Improve** tab in conversation its not showing the user details, its showing count 0.

I am using LITE plan and below is the code.

```
// conversation config
var conversation = new ConversationV1({
url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
username: process.env.CONVERSATION_USERNAME,
password: process.env.CONVERSATION_PASSWORD,
version_date: '2018-02-16',
version: 'v1',
context : {
        metadata : {
           "user_id": "{1234}"
           }
         },
headers: {'X-Watson-Metadata':'customer_id=user777;customer_id=xyz'}
});
```

app.js code:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ silent: true });

var express = require('express'); // app server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parser for post requests

//setup watson services
var ConversationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1'); // 
watson sdk
var DiscoveryV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/discovery/v1');

var app = express();
// Bootstrap application settings
 app.use(express.static('./public')); // load UI from public folder
 app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
// conversation config

var conversation = new ConversationV1({
url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
username: process.env.CONVERSATION_USERNAME || 'replace with the 
username',
password: process.env.CONVERSATION_PASSWORD || 'replace with the 
password',
version_date: '2018-02-16', //set currenct date, check here 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#versioning
version: 'v1',
context : {
metadata : {
   "user_id": "{1234}"
  }
 },
headers: {'X-Watson-Metadata':'customer_id=user777;customer_id=xyz'}
});
// Endpoint to be call from the client side for message
app.post('/api/message', (req, res) => {
var workspace = process.env.WORKSPACE_ID || '<workspace-id>';
if (!workspace || workspace === '<workspace-id>') {
    return res.json({
        'output': {
            'text': 'Please update the WORKSPACE_ID in your .env file with 
 your credential! If you did update, try to verify if the file are just 
with the name: .env'
        }
    });
  }
  var payload = {
    workspace_id: workspace,
    context: {},
    input: {}
 };
 if (req.body) {
    if (req.body.input) {
        payload.input = req.body.input;
    }
    if (req.body.context) {
        // The client must maintain context/state
        payload.context = req.body.context;
    }
 }
  // Send the input to the conversation service
 conversation.message(payload, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    updateMessage(res, payload, data);
 });
});
function updateMessage(res, input, response) {
if (!response.output) {
    response.output = {};
} else if (response.output && response.output.text) {
    return res.json(response);
}
}

 module.exports = app;
```

Comment: How do you send messages? The above looks like code to initialize the service.

Comment: i have added my app.js file code, please check

Comment: Please update with code after you applied my suggestion. I tested it and it works for me. See the image I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add the user id information to the **context**](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/logs_oview.html#user_id) that you send when calling the [message API](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant?language=node#get-response-to-user-input). Each request to Watson Assistant can have a different **userid**, e.g., when you have a multi-tenant application and your app / server handles multiple users and their requests in parallel.

Check out [the context section for the message call](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant?language=node#get-response-to-user-input), it has information about where to place that data in the JSON structure. You could merge your context updates into the message payload:

```
{
  workspace_id: '{workspace_id}',
  input: {'text': 'Hello'},
  context: {
       metadata : {
         "user_id": "{1234}"
       }
  }
}
```

Once your app has sent different user_id values, you should see the following in the **Improve** dashboard (I tested on my Lite plan with 2 user IDs). Different active users:

[image: 2 active users]

Average conversations per user:
[image: average conversations per user]

In addition, you can check the logs. In that conversation entries is the user_id field in the context metadata - the same your app sent as part of the message request.

Comment: thanks @data_henrik for your response.
You mean i need pass the user details in below payload context?
var payload = {
    workspace_id: workspace,
    context: {},
    input: {}

Comment: I have followed above steps and deployed my code, still I am not seeing user details in IMPROVE tab, its showing 0 users,
var payload = {
        workspace_id: workspace,
        context: {metadata : {
         "user_id": "{testuser}"
       }},
        input: {}
    };

Comment: Yes, i have got the response for the input

Comment: You cannot see user details in the Improve tab, only the averages are show. You would examine the actual logs. Of, if you have Plus or Premium plans, there would be user-specific billing info.

Comment: ok I am using Lite plan and i will not be able to see the user details.
But user averages also its showing NO data, do we need to use Plus/Premium planes only to see both user details and averages  ?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? I can see the user_id in the metadata under context.

Comment: Apologies for late response @data_henrik, i am able to see the user details in IMPROVE tab now.  if i use the premium service I will get the report of per person api calls details in IMPROVE tab right ? (Please let me know where i can see the report details)

Comment: hi @data_henrik, i tried with stranded plan with above code, I am not able to see the user  details in Active user tab, its showing NO data,

    var payload = {
        workspace_id: workspace,
        context: {
  metadata : {
   
         "user_id":"{user1234}"   
       }},
        input: {}
  
    };

Comment: user details are updated now but i am not able to see the user id and its api calls details in IMPROVE tab, I want get the report of that now. I am using Stranded plan.

Comment: The details are in the logs, billing info etc. is for Premium plans (I have no experience with that).

Comment: okay @data_henrik, I have checked logs and billing/usage tabs but user based details are not there. i have opened a case with IBM team and they are working on this. thanks for your help.

Comment: @data_henrik I have a doubt regarding the user calculation for Watson in case of integration with Intercom. Are the visitors calculated as users for pricing purpose in Watson?