# What is the Customer ID to delete logs from a Watson Assistant Workspace?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In WA workspace in the improve section (watsonplatform.net/eu-de/WA_INSTANCE_ID/workspaces/WA_WORKSPACE_ID/improve/userdata) I can see all the conversations users had with our chatbot.

I would like to try to delete these utilising the delete labeled data api - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant?curl=#delete-labeled-data

**The api call:**

> deletes all data associated with a specified customer ID. The method
>   has no effect if no data is associated with the customer ID.

Where can I find the Customer ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented here [in the docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant/information-security.html#information-security) you have to set a header on your /message POST requests, which associates that message with the customer ID sent.

The example is

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:3Df... ...Y7Pc9"
 --header
   'Content-Type: application/json'
   'X-Watson-Metadata: customer_id=abc'
 --data
   '{"input":{"text":"hello"}}'
  'https://gateway-eu-de.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{workspaceID}/message?version=2018-09-20'
```

You have to create and set the customer ID, which could be a user ID, UUID session ID or some other unique identifier to a user of your bot.

If you have been sending messages in without a customer ID, then it does not look like these can be deleted.

If you are using user analytics as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667751/ibm-watson-assistant-how-to-enable-user-metrics/53668917#53668917) then I would recommend setting the user_id to the same value as customer ID.

If using the NodeJS SDK the headers are set in the payload in the call to message:

```
var payload = {
  workspace_id: workspace,
  context: req.body.context || {},
  input: req.body.input || {}
}
payload.headers = {'X-Watson-Metadata': `customer_id=${req.session.id}`}
assistant.message(payload, (err, data) => {
...
```

Comment: If the ids are not set and it's an emergency, you can open a support ticket to get logs deleted. But IBM is only able to delete all logs, they cannot see the content of the logs. So make a local backup of the logs if needed.

Comment: Whats the python version of this? I am sending headers as headers = {'X-Watson-Metadata': 'customer_id=abc'} just like another argument.