# How to map a Watson Assistant conversation to a user of my application?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I integrated a Watson Assistant to my Website. To access the assistant, a user needs to log in. Now in my frontend, I know who my user is. When the user goes to the page with the watson assistant, I want to store some information of the conversation my user had with the chatbot. In my frontend I create the chatbot by including a provided script link.

When retrieving all Logs of the chatbot, I get all the conversations with conversation_ids and user_ids generated by IBM.

How do I map those IBM-generated ids to my application user-ids?

Can I somehow pass my application user_id to watson when opening the chatbot, so I can use Webhooks to post the conversation_id and my application user_id to the backend and save it there?
Or is there another way to do that? What are best practices on how to do that?

Or do I have to start conversations in a programmatic way, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667751/ibm-watson-assistant-how-to-enable-user-metrics)?

Comment: Do you already use the techniques as described in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-web-chat-develop-userid and https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-web-chat-security#web-chat-security-authenticate?

Comment: No, thank you for the hint. We currently only perform the instance.render(). That might be just what I needed. I will soon give an update if that worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to send the user id to Watson Assistant is by using https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#updateuserid

You can then use pre or post message webhook to send to your backend your `conversation_id` and the `user_id`.
The `user_id` you have set via the above method will appear in `context.global.system.user_id`.

More info can be found at: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-web-chat-develop-userid